# "Show deleted" checkbox not working as intended

Tags: java, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

I've implemented a soft delete behavior in my imaginary Video rental app, and now I am trying to implement a way to reactivate my "deleted" customers, but I can't get my approach to work, surely something simple, but google did not let me find the answer, so here I am.

Here is an excerpt from my repo interface (JpaRepository):

```
  @Query("select m from Movie m where m.isDeleted = true")
  List<Movie> findAllIsDeleted();

  @Override
  @Query("select m from Movie m where m.isDeleted=false")
  List<Movie> findAll();

  @Modifying
  @Transactional
  @Query("update Movie m set m.isDeleted=true where id=?1")
  void softDelete(Long id);
```

In my service class I have:

```
  public List<Movie> findAllMovies(String filterText) {
    if (filterText == null || filterText.isEmpty()) {
      return movieRepository.findAll();
    } else {
      return movieRepository.search(filterText);
    }
  }

  public List<Movie> findAllDeletedMovies() {
    return movieRepository.findAllIsDeleted();
  }
```

And an excerpt from my listview class looks like:

```
...
  Checkbox showDeleted = new Checkbox("Show deleted movies", e -> {
    updateList();
    Notification.show(e.getValue().toString());
  });
...
  private void updateList() {
    if (showDeleted.getValue() == true) {
      grid.setItems(service.findAllDeletedMovies());
    }
    grid.setItems(service.findAllMovies(filterText.getValue()));
  }
```

But obviously there is something wrong in the listener part, or there is a silent "sure we want to help feature" that I am not aware of. Because the updateList function is not executed. What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the implementation of your `updateList` method.

No matter if the value of the checkbox is true, at the end it always sets the items again that are returned by `service::findAllMovies`.

move the last statement into an `else` block and it should work.

```
private void updateList() {
    if (showDeleted.getValue()) { // btw, if(boolValue == true) is redundant. just do if(boolValue)
        grid.setItems(service.findAllDeletedMovies());
    } else {
        grid.setItems(service.findAllMovies(filterText.getValue()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Don’t Know you data table design,
but you can try this

"select m.* from Movie m where m.isDeleted = true"

Comment: Thanks, the problem is not the query, it is for reference, the problem is that the updateList() method don't get executed when I check/un-check the showDeleted checkbox....

Comment: always use formatter and provide details + output